# unable to get a string from a function and display with out duplication of strcpy and strcat command

Tags: c, string, function, pointers

I am trying to pass a string from a function, copy it, concatenate with other string and display in the main function. But I need to duplicate strcpy and strcat commands to get the answer I need.

MY warnings:

test1.c:15:1: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]

test1.c:22:9: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type

/usr/include/string.h:125:14: note: expected ‘char * **restrict**’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’

test1.c:23:9: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcat’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type

/usr/include/string.h:133:14: note: expected ‘char * **restrict**’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’

test1.c:31:3: warning: return discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type

test1.c:31:3: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *return_string(int number) {
    char out1[5] = "";
    switch (number) {
      case 1: strcpy(out1, "hi");  break;
      case 2: strcpy(out1, "how"); break;
      case 3: strcpy(out1, "are"); break;
      case 4: strcpy(out1, "you"); break;
      case 5: strcpy(out1, "?");   break;
    } 
    return out1;
}

char *decimal_to_string (int dec_number) {
    int num = dec_number;
    char const final_str[12] = "Hi ", tmp_str[12] = ""; // result    

    strcpy(tmp_str, return_string(num));
    strcat(final_str, tmp_str);
    strcpy(tmp_str, return_string(num));
    strcat(final_str, tmp_str);
    printf("direct return string: %s\n", return_string(num));
    printf("return string: %s\n", final_str);

    return final_str;   
}

int main() {
    int num = 3;
    const char *szSomeString = decimal_to_string(num); 
    printf("%s", szSomeString);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Returning the local array `out1` yields undefined behavior.

Comment: for gcc sake: read the warnings: they're useful. What would have been useful would have been you posting the warnings in your question, instead of making us try to manually compile your code.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a pointer to a local variable (`out1` and `final_str`) but local variables are destroyed when exiting the function. Thus using the returned pointer causes undefined behavior.

Here's how you could do it instead:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

const char *return_string(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1: return "hi";
        case 2: return "how";
        case 3: return "are";
        case 4: return "you";
        case 5: return "?";
    } 
    return "";
}

char *decimal_to_string(int dec_number) {
    char *final_str = malloc(12); // allocate dynamic memory (will not be released on return)
    strcpy(final_str, "Hi ");
    char tmp_str[12] = ""; // result    

    strcpy(tmp_str, return_string(dec_number));
    strcat(final_str, tmp_str);
    strcpy(tmp_str, return_string(dec_number));
    strcat(final_str, tmp_str);
    printf("direct return string: %s\n", return_string(dec_number));
    printf("return string: %s\n", final_str);

    return final_str;
}

int main(void) {
    int num = 3;
    char *szSomeString = decimal_to_string(num); 
    printf("%s", szSomeString);
    free(szSomeString); // deallocate the allocated memory
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, If I need to return a string from a function either I have to directly return the string or use dynamic memory.

Comment: There are other ways to return strings but these are appropriate for your situation. Just make sure to not return pointers to local variables.

Answer (score 0):

You could either declare **out1** (in `return_string()`) as a global variable outside the function, or inside the function as *static*. That way you can `strcat()` to the (global variable) **out1** or to a pointer returned by return_string(), and avoid strcpy/strcat.

Of course, doing so, you gain something but you lose something else: the reentrancy (don't know a better word) of the logic and the possibility to make it multi-threaded.

Of the two ways (**out1** global *or* static), probably the global one is better because it does not hide the logic.